# Azure Pipeline Agent get triggered but results in old pipeline run

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-agent

i've got a build pipeline which is triggered every three hours from 06:00 on forward.
In total i've got 8 build agents.
Agent 1 shows me that it was triggered around 15:57 with a new run.
[Here you can see the build which is triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwe2s.png)
The Job Number is increased, but it refers to a build that is 15 days old.
I can't get a hold of, from where the build is triggered.
Do you guys have any idea, where I should be looking?
Regards
Markus

I looked everywhere, from where the pipeline could have been triggered.

Comment: The information is so limited that I am unable to understand how the pipeline is scheduled to trigger. Can you please share some more screenshots of the trigger/schedule settings of the pipeline. If the pipeline is defined by a YAML file, please also share the `schedules` information of the YAML. You may also share a screenshot with the recent runs/builds of this specific pipeline, which will help us understand how the pipeline is triggered.

Comment: Search about the pipeline triggers.

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check then answer below? If it resolved your query, please consider marking the answer, which will help others with similar concerns. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it appears they are different pipelines cause one name is longer.

I can reproduce the same, and it could happen when you re-run the failed job:

[image]

[image]

You can click into the pipeline(job 59023 in your screenshot), it will show how it triggerred, and timestamp(it's still the **first old trigger** and time):
[image: ![enter image description here]

check the detail log, if it contains `attempts`, and `toggle on the timestamp` in the log to confirm the details.

[image]

[image]

[image]